# FormattedNumber in react-intl does not wrap currency to round bracket if it is negative in chrome

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

When i use `FormattedNumber` from `react-intl` to format currency, it won't format negative currency amount to have parenthesis around the currency in chrome.

It does work in Internet Explorer but does not work in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

```
<FormattedNumber  
                        style='currency'
                        currency='USD'
                        minimumFractionDigits={2}
                        maximumFractionDigits={2}
                        value={-100.100}/>
```

> Output in IE -> ($100.10)
>
> Output in Chrome-> -$100.10

Is there any option to get ($100.10) in Chrome/Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

`react-intl` uses [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) under the hood. That has a `currencySign` option, which can be `standard` or `accounting`. Set it to `accounting` to use parentheses for negative values. Using the FormattedNumber component:

```
<FormattedNumber  
  style='currency'
  currency='USD'
  currencySign='accounting'
  minimumFractionDigits={2}
  maximumFractionDigits={2}
  value={-100.100}
/>
```

Comment: As I posted it long way back in past. i will reconfirm it and accept the answer